# Simple ArrayList to readable HTML

Tags: java, android, html, arraylist

I'm trying to output an arraylist to a readable html or text file.  I figure this should be pretty simple, but it is simply evading me.  So here it is.  I have a log file that is populated when a player gets knocked out of a game.  Here's the screen shot:
[image: screen cap of busted player log]

I then hit the save log button to export it to a file.  Whether the file is html or txt, the output is really unusable:
[image: output file]

So how do I get my html or text file to show as it does in the on screen activity?

Thanks,
Hendo

Here's the code for the activity...

```
import static com.feltinghendo.www.pokerdbtest.MainActivity.userList;
```

public class GameLog extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private static final String TAG = "GameLog";

```
TextView gameLog;
ListView lvLog;
Button btnSave, btnClear;

private static ArrayList<String> bustOutLog = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_log);

    gameLog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGameLog);
    lvLog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLog);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

    gameLog.setText("Game Log");

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String bustLog = extras.getString("BUSTED");
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + bustLog);
        bustOutLog.add(bustLog);
    }

    lvLog.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bustOutLog);
    lvLog.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    lvLog.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick: starts");

            String undoBust = bustOutLog.get(position);
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick: UNDO str = " + undoBust);

            String[] cut = undoBust.split(" ");
            String undo = cut[0];
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick: remove player " + undo);

            String sql = "UPDATE players SET active = 1 WHERE name = '" + undo + "'";

            Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick: undo sql" + sql);
            userList.execSQL(sql);
```

//              MainActivity.userList.execSQL("UPDATE players SET active = 1 WHERE name = '" + undo + "'");

```
            UserList.boughtIn.add(undo);

            bustOutLog.remove(position);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
    });

    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    UserList.spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}



public void saveLog(View view) {

    // get permission - if we don't already have permission, we must request it from the user.
    // Very quick solution - DO NOT JUST DO THIS IN PRODUCTION CODE! Refer to Section 10.
    int hasWriteESPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (hasWriteESPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: permission granted");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: requesting permission");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos =
                new FileOutputStream(
                        new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "gamelog.html"));
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(bustOutLog);
        os.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "saveLog: File written");
        Toast.makeText(this, "File Written", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "saveLog: File Not Written");
        Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Written", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void clearLog(View view) {
    bustOutLog.clear();
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to go this route with positive results.

```
 File logFile = new File(basePath, "gamelog.txt");
            FileWriter ofs = new FileWriter(logFile);
            BufferedWriter outStream = new BufferedWriter(ofs);
            for (int i=0; i < bustOutLog.size(); i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: writing " + bustOutLog.get(i));
                outStream.write(bustOutLog.get(i));
                outStream.write(String.format("\n"));
            }
            outStream.close();
            ofs.close();
```

With help from one of my instructors, I was able to get this working just fine.

I will say that I had to use Notepad++ to read the text file properly (with the line breaks), as Windows Notepad wouldn't recognize the line break in the text.  I find that rather curious.

I appreciate all of your help with this.  I did attempt this using the StringBuilder, as suggested here.  It did work, though it didn't eliminate all of the extra characters that seemed to be put into the text file.  I assume it was my newby code work.  :-)

Thanks all!
Hendo

Answer (score 0):

There's no code here, so we cannot really tell what's your problem but I assume it is with your log writing. So, in case you store Strings in your ArrayList you can do the following which works just fine for me in a very similar situation

```
FileWriter logger = new FileWriter("log.txt"); 
for(String line: listLog) { //listLog being 
logger.write(line);
}
logger.close();
```

PS: You can loop through your array list using lambda expressions, it is a better pratice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code, but it looks like you are missing to give some format to the output.

Create a StringBuffer.

Loop through your list and append to the StringBuffer

StringBuffer toString() method will give you the whole string which you can then output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to convert your ArrayList to String.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
for (String s : list)
{ 
  sb.append(s); sb.append("\n"); 
}
```

Then you can use **sb.toString()** while writing content to a file.